# Java generic convert byte array to string (Non hex, decimal)

Tags: java, arrays, string

What is the best way to convert a byte array to a string with a radix of choice? There is a ton of examples here on S.O. and elsewhere to convert to a hex string. What I am mainly interested in here is converting to something ***other*** than a hex or decimal string; also a more generic way.

This is what I currently do:

```
byte[] input;
String MyStr = new BigInteger(input).toString(radix);
```

This works, but since Java has a concept of radix, as used in the [Integer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29). This seems to be the explicit purpose as defined in [Character](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#MAX_RADIX). Shouldn't there be a better way of doing this rather than to first convert the byte array to a BigInteger? It feels like my Java knowledge misses some essential standard class?

EDIT:
I would like to use this for a compressed way of representing (and printing) raw binary data of different types. This is the actual radix I currently use:

```
String MyStr = new BigInteger(data).toString(Character.MAX_RADIX);
```

The MAX_RADIX (36) uses a combination of lower case letters and numbers. This gives a decent compression, but would be even better if the radix could include UPPER letters, which is why I thought I may be missing something.

Comment: Can you give examples of the bytes and what you expect as the result?

Comment: It looks like a very object oriented way to me, you get the value representation which is then translated to string. Are you worried about performance? The code at least is self explanatory.

Comment: @Bohemian. Made a slight edit to include my usage radix.

Comment: I'm assuming your input is a `byte[]`, not a `Byte[]`, since there's no BigInteger constructor that takes a `Byte[]`.

Comment: @ericbn. Right! I changed it to byte[].

Comment: What are you going to do with the resulting String? Does it need to be human readable?

Comment: @Bohemian. Yes, At least readable by me and an advanced user, for getting a sense of the data, similarities etc. Base64 as suggested works fine for this, and some type of data may need to be binary or hex, depending on the data type. The suggested solution is not generic, but at least I now have a higher radix. Seems there really isn't any generic way of setting the radix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you're looking for [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoding. This uses 64 different characters to encode a value: upper case and lower case letters (that's 52 characters already), digits (10 more, including the '0'), and the '+' and '/' symbols (or '-' and '_' in the url-safe variation).

If you're using Java 8, there's the [Base64](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html) class:

```
String str = Base64.Encoder.encodeToString(data);
```

Otherwise, Apache Commons has a [Base64](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html) class too:

```
String str = Base64.encodeBase64String(data);
```

Comment: Thanks! This is useful, and great its now part of Java8. I should have thought of that. I still sometimes need the radix to be 2 and 16 for debugging, but for the most part, Base64 should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

That's a good one, actually, I'm not sure neither if there's a class to achieve that. But another way to do what you want without using BigInteger is to iterate over the array and get the output, something like:

```
for(byte b : input){
    System.out.print(Integer.toString(b & 0xFF, radix));
}
```

Not sure about an specific class doing a conversion, but this is another approach I know, maybe could be useful to you or to somebody else.

Happy coding.

Regards.